# Incorrect data sampling using two collections MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**ChatsUsers** - this collection is needed to control the filtering of messages, for example, if a user has cleared the history of correspondence - it is only for himself, he cleared it. How this works is simple, the **`start_message_id`** - current date is specified which lets you know to return messages `message collection` with **`create_date`** greater than or equal to the new **`start_message_id`**.

```golang
type ChatsUsers struct {
    ID     string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    ChatID string `json:"chat_id" bson:"chat_id"`
    UserID string `json:"user_id" bson:"user_id"`
    StartMessageID int64 `json:"start_message_id,omitempty" bson:"start_message_id"`
    EndMessageID int64 `json:"end_message_id,omitempty" bson:"end_message_id"`
}
```

```golang
type Message struct {
    ID         string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    ChatID     string `json:"chat_id" bson:"chat_id"`
    FromID     string `json:"from_id" bson:"from_id"`
    CreateDate int64  `json:"create_date" bson:"create_date"`
    Body     string `json:"body" bson:"body"`
    UpdateAt int64  `json:"update_at" bson:"update_at"`
    ...
}
```

```golang
type Chat struct {
    ID           string   `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    Participants []string `json:"participants" bson:"participants"`
    LastMessage  *Message `json:"last_message,omitempty" bson:"last_message"`
    ...
}
```

Which is what I'm trying to do now in the example below. I need to find all last messages `$last_message` (see aggregation I wrote) for each chat which creation time `$last_message.create_date` is greater than or equal to `chatsusers.start_message_id`.

My problem, my option doesn't work the way I want it to, it doesn't select one message, and `$gte` doesn't work. I may not have written the query quite correctly, but I'm working on it still

My question: how do I get **ONE** last message for each chat that has a creation time `$last_message.create_date` greater than or equal to `chatsusers.start_message_id`?

[My try](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hQdekKtM5Y_)

Answer (score 1):

You are actually very close. Just remember when using sub-pipeline in `$lookup`, if you need to access values in the "from" collection, you will need to put it in a variable in `let` clause. (i.e. `$chat_user.start_message_id` in your case)

When you access the values in "to" collection, you don't need to put the new name of the `$lookup` result in the sub-pipeline. (i.e. `$last_message.create_date` should be simply `$create_date`)

```js
db.chat.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      participants: "63ce54460aeee5e72c778d90"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chatsusers",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "chat_id",
      as: "chat_user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$chat_user"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "message",
      localField: "id",
      foreignField: "chat_id",
      let: {
        smid: "$chat_user.start_message_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gte: [
                "$create_date",
                "$$smid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            create_date: -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      as: "last_message",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$last_message",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "create_date": {
        $first: "$create_date"
      },
      "id": {
        $first: "$_id"
      },
      "last_message": {
        $max: "$last_message"
      },
      "owner_id": {
        $first: "$owner_id"
      },
      "participants": {
        $first: "$participants"
      },
      "title": {
        $first: "$title"
      },
      "type": {
        $first: "$type"
      },
      "unread": {
        $first: "$unread"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      title: 1,
      create_date: 1,
      type: 1,
      participants: 1,
      owner_id: 1,
      last_message: "$last_message",
      unread: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YepNgqgomfh)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have this problem, why is there always a duplicate in the reply, and more interestingly, why does the first entry work with the `$last_message.create_date` condition greater than or equal to `chatsusers.start_message_id`, but the second returns the last message? How to get only one record without duplicates? In my example, the first object is correct and the second is a duplicate of the first: https://mongoplayground.net/p/6PfO-DNoxXh.
The second example, where only duplicates (I just changed `chatsusers.start_message_id`) https://mongoplayground.net/p/lUF6gt21n4d

Comment: @alex In your first playground, the `start_message_id` is actually slightly larger than `create_date`(30 more). So, it is expected for it to be left out in the sub pipeline `$match`

Comment: Okay, but in the second example, I also get duplicates. Can you tell me how I can get rid of them?

Comment: @alex As `chat_user` may have multiple lookup results, the `$unwind` is causing duplicates. Updated the answer to use a `$group` to dedupe.